# Crystal Report 13 Pie Chart

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have a simple report with no grouping. The report shows count of jobs as shown below:

```
Job                   Submitted                        Delayed
 A                        10                              01
 B                        20                              10
 C                        30                              05
 D                        15                              12
                    TOTAL:75                        TOTAL:28
```

In Report footer section I have added a pie chart. I want pie chart to show two sections. 
onse section will be **(28/75)*100 = 37.33%** and other section as **62.67%**. I spent more than 6 hours to achieve this but I am not able to do it. Is it possible to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: where you are facing the issue? any error?

Comment: Did not received any error. crystal has three options namely on change of, for each records and for all records. I used all of them but did not received correct output. Pie should show one section of 37.33% and other section of 62.67% but I am getting output which is a lot different. Not sure what is happening

Comment: what output you are getting?

Comment: pie chart sums up 75 and 28 to get 103 as total and then divide 103 into (28/103)*100 = 27.18  and (75/103)*100 = 72.82

Comment: Please check the formula properly being applied here as this is the issue, that data is not being taken properly in the chart.